# JPA entities returned as HAL+JSON

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I am re-writing a service we have as a REST controller in spring. An agent using a .NET thick client calls the RESTful webservice and based on the agent security profile, data they are allowed to access will be returned.

I have that all coded, but I need to return the data in application/hal+json format. I have been trying to to see how spring-data-rest accomplishes it but I am leery of copying and pasting code from spring-data-rest-webmvc to accomplish this(Most of the classes are default package protected and methods private).

I am also making use of spring-data-rest in this project, but I need to call the controller I have written for GET methods to retrieve data.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spring has an [existing](http://projects.spring.io/spring-hateoas/) project for HAL+JSON that you can just bolt on to yours.